# Not able to reconnect to outlook MailBox using spring integration and imap idle

Tags: spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I am using spring integration and i am getting below exception when the server keeps IDLE for sometime. I am not able to reproduce the below exception.

```
Caused by: javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3199)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3043)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:2995)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:220)
    ... 10 common frames omitted



The below exeption is thrown from java mail 1.5

Please help me in reproducing this issue and fix for this issue. Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

The server will time out the connection if it's idle for too long.  You need to poke the server every 20 - 30 minutes to keep the connection alive, e.g., using Folder.getMessageCount.  (Of course, the connection can still break for all sorts of other reasons, so you have to be prepared to handle that in any case.)

Comment: .from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter(mailImapUrl)
                                .searchTermStrategy((f, l) -> fromAndNotSeenTerm())
                                .javaMailProperties(p -> p
                                        .put("mail.debug", mailDebug)
                                        .put("mail.imap.connectionpoolsize", mailImapConnectionPoolSize))  This is code i used in the integration flow. Can you add some snippet?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't use Spring. You need a timer of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning log; the adapter will reconnect after this exception.

If you want to suppress the log message, reduce the log level for that category to `ERROR`.

**EDIT**

It will reconnect 10 seconds after the failure, unless you have changed `reconnectDelay` ...

```
@Test
public void testIdleReconnects() throws Exception {
    ImapMailReceiver receiver = spy(new ImapMailReceiver("imap:foo"));
    receiver.setBeanFactory(mock(BeanFactory.class));
    receiver.afterPropertiesSet();
    ImapIdleChannelAdapter adapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(receiver);
    Folder folder = mock(Folder.class);
    willThrow(new FolderClosedException(folder, "test")).given(receiver).waitForNewMessages();
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    taskScheduler.initialize();
    adapter.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
    adapter.afterPropertiesSet();
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3); << exit test after 3
    adapter.setApplicationEventPublisher(e -> {
        latch.countDown();
    });
    adapter.start();
    assertTrue(latch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}
```

If you are not seeing logs similar to these, you should edit your question with complete configuration and logs - you should also try setting the javamail property `mail.debug` to `true` to see the activity.

This is what the above test produces for me...

```
2017-02-26 12:59:43,977 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] DEBUG: ImapIdleChannelAdapter - waiting for mail
2017-02-26 12:59:43,982 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] WARN : ImapIdleChannelAdapter - error occurred in idle task
javax.mail.FolderClosedException: test
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:243)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-02-26 12:59:43,984 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] WARN : ImapIdleChannelAdapter - Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure in 'idle' task. Will resubmit.
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:296)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:243)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.mail.FolderClosedException: test
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277)
    ... 10 more
2017-02-26 12:59:53,989 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] DEBUG: ImapIdleChannelAdapter - waiting for mail
2017-02-26 12:59:53,990 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] WARN : ImapIdleChannelAdapter - error occurred in idle task
javax.mail.FolderClosedException: test
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:243)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-02-26 12:59:53,991 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] WARN : ImapIdleChannelAdapter - Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure in 'idle' task. Will resubmit.
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:296)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:243)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.mail.FolderClosedException: test
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277)
    ... 10 more
2017-02-26 13:00:03,997 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] DEBUG: ImapIdleChannelAdapter - waiting for mail
2017-02-26 13:00:03,997 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] WARN : ImapIdleChannelAdapter - error occurred in idle task
javax.mail.FolderClosedException: test
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:243)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-02-26 13:00:03,998 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] WARN : ImapIdleChannelAdapter - Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure in 'idle' task. Will resubmit.
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:296)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:243)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.mail.FolderClosedException: test
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277)
    ... 10 more
```

As you can see, we attempt to reconnect every 10 seconds.

Comment: It did not connect to mailbox once the below exception occurs. Thats the problem.

Comment: See the edit to my answer - the adapter will reconnect 10 seconds after the failure, by default.

Comment: What version of Spring Integration are you using? This was broken in 4.0.4 and 3.0.5 (and fixed in 4.0.5 and 3.0.6). See [INT-3536](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3536). The current version is 4.3.7.

Comment: spring-integration-mail-4.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: I just tested against 4.1.6 and everything worked as expected - reconnected after the default 10 seconds. So, something else is going on in your environment - perhaps take a thread dump next time it happens.